# Is it best to install Windows 7 with lowest memory possible and then later add more?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory

Is it best to install Windows with as little memory as possible, then later install more?

An anecdote: I have an old Dell D600 with 512 MB of RAM and a 1.4 GHz Centrino with fresh install of Windows 7 Home Premium. I replaced the wireless card with Broadcom G and installed proper drivers. It was far more responsive than I initially expected! Then I found a leftover stick of 1 GB PC2700 memory laying around. I replaced one of the two 256 MB sticks with this, and it feels much faster than before.

Is there something to be said for starving a Windows 7 install so that it automatically optimizes under starved conditions, so that when more RAM is added, it runs faster than if the intended RAM total were initially installed?

Comment: Get rid of the caps please!

Comment: Umm, yes adding RAM makes your system faster. What is odd about this?

Comment: No, I don't think there is any evidence to suggest that. (@terdon: I believe the asker wants to know whether there are advantages to installing Windows with low RAM and later adding more instead of installing all the RAM from the get-go.)

Answer (score 5):

No. Windows will dynamically adapt to the amount of RAM that's available for system. There's no need to limit its RAM during installation.

Performance will also depend on the amount of virtual memory assigned to your system. By default Windows will manage it automatically, it should be just fine until you want some very specific setup. To edit virtual memory settings, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type: `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`, then click OK. In the new window click the first *Settings* button and click the *Advanced* tab, virtual memory settings will be there.